# how to clear the file input binding in aurelia

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

Aurelia binding with file input works perfectly fine but when I use a clear function that simply resets the model property to empty array, the binding gets cleared but the browser file input keeps showing the name of the selected file.

```
 <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file-upload" files.bind="selectedFiles" change.delegate="generatePreview()" aria-describedby="fileUploadHelp" ref="selectedFiles">
```

This is my current html and on the model side I simpley added a `selectedFiles` as empty array

Now when I try to clear the input,

```
clearFiles() {
    this.selectedFiles = [];
    // this.selectedFiles = null; setting to null also produces same results
}
```

It does work, and clears the data from the model.

But the browser file input keeps showing the name of the selected file in the input control.

With jquery mindset, or simple JS, it will be easy to add a line to access the input and set value to `''`.

```
document.getElementById("file-upload").value = null;
```

But shouldn't this work with binding as well?

Am I missing something obvious?

PS: I tested in latest chrome and firefox and behaviour is identical.

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, in vanilla JS you'd set the `value` to null. So, simply add a `value` binding to your input:

```
<input type="file" value.bind='val' files.bind='selectedFiles' />
```

And in your class, set `val` to null:

```
clearFiles() {
    this.val = null;
}
```